# How to get anchor tag text to a variable and display as innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have given code below. I want that a variable of JS take anchor tag text as input and display in another Element through innerHTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p><a class="myAnchor" href="http://www.microsoft.com">www.microsoft.com</a>
    <a class="myAnchor" href="http://www.microsoft.com">www.microsoft.com</a></p>

    <p>Click the button to change the value of the href attribute of the link above to "www.cnn.com".</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      var x=$(".myAnchor").on("click",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).text();
      });

      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong?

Instead of assigning the click event to a variable, assign the inner text of the clicked link in a variable and on clicking the button assign this variable to the required element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a class="myAnchor" href="http://www.microsoft.com">www.microsoft.com1</a>
      <a class="myAnchor" href="http://www.microsoft.com">www.microsoft.com2</a>
    </p>

    <p>
      Click the button to change the value of the href attribute of the link
      above to "www.cnn.com".
    </p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      var x = '';
      $(".myAnchor").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        x = $(this).text();
      });
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```